# Working with Hexadecimal numbers

Tags: c, casting

I am working with a command line tool which accepts different arguments and does various operations using them.

My first argument is the base address of a [*NOR memory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#NOR_memories) and says it is `0x6000000`. Since it is passed as an `argv` it is of type `char *`.

I pass this value as the `FILE_SYSTEM_BASE_ADDRESS` and use it in this equation:

```
start_addr = FILE_SYSTEM_BASE_ADDRESS + (NOR_FS_MIN_BCLK_SIZE * FILE_SYSTEM_SECTOR_NUMBER);
```

All the other values in the equation are of `uint32_t` type. For now, I use typecasting to convert the `char*` into `uint32_t` which obviously gives it a new `uint32_t` value.

---

**My question is:**

1. Is there a way I can get this type of format?

   ```
   start_addr = 0x600000 + (NOR_FS_MIN_BCLK_SIZE * FILE_SYSTEM_SECTOR_NUMBER)
   ```
2. Will the value obtained by the original equation and the current method give wrong `start_addr` values?

Currently, if I use this statement

```
printf(Image File Start Offset: 0x%x\n , start_addr);
```

I get `0x67` as result.

Am I handling the arguments correctly?

Comment: I think we need to see a [mcve]

Comment: Are you asking how to parse a uint32_t from a string?

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem:

> ... I use type casting to convert the char* into uint32_t ....

If someone runs your program like this:

```
foo 0x600000
```

then the `arg[1]` entry will be the *address of a string* that has the value `"0x600000"`.  The address of the string can be cast do a `uint32_t`, but that's going to convert the string's address rather than the value the string represents.  The address of the string is useless to you, except as a way to access the string.

To convert the value represented by the string to a number, you can use a library function like `strtoul`:

```
uint32_t FILE_SYSTEM_BASE_ADDRESS = strtoul(arg[1], NULL, 0);
```

Check the documentation to learn more about `strtoul`.  Never cast just because the compiler says something is the wrong type.  Figure out the right way to convert what you have to what you need.  *Sometimes* that's a cast, but often it is not.

Comment: Thank you Adrian.. I ended up using strtoul as well. Thank you anyways :)